# navigation.setOptions() doesn't work in React Native (expo environment)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I am having problems with navigation in React Native (Expo environment).
I want to put a save button on `headerRight` in `"SingleProductEditScreen"` using `navigation.setOptions()`, but the error message is thrown which is given in the attached `ss`.

[image]

Also, since this button needs access to the component state, I don't want to make outside using

```
"SingleProductEditScreen.navigationOptions()"
```

How to access and modify the header section in `"SingleProductEditScreen"` component?

```
    const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Categories: CategoriesScreen,
        Recipe: RecipeScreen,
        RecipesList: RecipesListScreen,
        Ingredient: IngredientScreen,
        Search: SearchScreen,
        IngredientsDetails: IngredientsDetailsScreen,
        Orders:OrdersScreen,
        SingleOrder:SingleOrder,
        OrderDetails:OrderDetailsScreen,
        Register:RegisterScreen,
        Edit:EditScreen,
        EditScreenSingle:SingleProductEditScreen
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        //headerMode: 'float',
        
        defaulfNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            flex: 1,
          },
        })
      }
    ); 



    const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Main: MainNavigator
      },
      {
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        initialRouteName: 'Main',
        drawerWidth: 250,
        contentComponent: DrawerContainer
      }
    );


     
    export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(DrawerStack);
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<!-- end snippet -->

<!-- begin snippet: DrawerContainer.js -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    export default class DrawerContainer extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <MenuButton
                title="HOME"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/home.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Home');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
              <MenuButton
                title="CATEGORIES"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/category.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Categories');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
              <MenuButton
                title="SEARCH"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/search.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Search');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
              <MenuButton
                title="ORDERS"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/order.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Orders');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
              <MenuButton
                title="REGISTER"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/register.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Register');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
                <MenuButton
                title="EDIT CONTENT"
                source={require('../../../assets/icons/edit.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Edit');
                  navigation.closeDrawer();
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



    const EditScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)((props)=>{
        console.log('props in Edit page: ',props);
        const {navigation}=props;
        const productEditHandler=(product)=>{
          props.navigation.navigate('EditScreenSingle', { product });
        };
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>







const SingleProductEditScreen= connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)((props)=>{
    const {navigation}=props;
    const product=props.navigation.state.params.product;
    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
                navigation.setOptions({
                    headerRight: () =>
                        <HeaderBtnSave
                            loading={saveBtnState===SAVE_BTN_LOADING}
                            disabled={saveBtnState!==SAVE_BTN_ON}
                            onPress={() => onSavePress()}
                        />
                    })
            }, [navigation]);
    return (
        <Text>some text</Text>
    )
})
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please do not display error messages as images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to format the code references in your paragraph with a tick on each end.

Answer (score 0):

navigation.setOption is available in v5 while it seems you are using v4.x, so you have to use the following method to update the header in your `SingleProductEditScreen` component

```
class SingleProductEditScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="Info"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
  };
}

  // etc..
}
```

Link to doc [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/header-buttons)